# Remove All Styles and Indent from Ordered List

Tags: html, css, list

How do I remove the indent and style of an ordered list, so that it behaves like regular text?

Example:

```
   1. Item
   1. Item
   [...]
1000. Item
```

Should look like this:

```
1. Item
2. Item
[...]
1000. Item 100
```

Code:

```
<ol>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would unset the vendor/user-agent `padding` and `margin` property values on the containing list element (`ol` or `ul`), essentially *normalizing* the element styles.
You would still need to account for the space required to see the `list-item` display type, you can do this by declaring a `margin` property on the nested list-items and adjusting the value to suit requirements.

```
ol {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    margin-left: 10px; /* Adjust accordingly */
}
```

```css
ol.normalized {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

ol.normalized li {
    margin-left: 10px; /* Adjust accordingly */
}
```

```html
<h4>Normalized</h4>

<ol class="normalized">
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>

<h4>Initial</h4>

<ol>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
  <li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way I can do this without using an arbitrary margin-left, so this would work on a responsive design?

Comment: That would be dependent on the number of list items you are expecting, you should be settling with a value that would account for the highest number, so if you will have 100 list-items the `margin` property value you declare should be large enough to accommodate this value. This will still maintain an even text-indentation for every list-item. If you want something more dynamic, you'll probably want to make your numbered lists inline elements so that they occupy space in the document flow and "push" the list item content as far out as required, but then your text indentation will not be even.

Comment: That would not be an issue. Thanks for explaining!

Comment: Happy to help. Now go forth and conquer those list items!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to put display css property for example to inline-block

`li{
display:inline-block;
}`

```css
li{
display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<ol>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
<li>Item</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this also removes the numbering.